# Qt | How to get the orginal id from a Widget?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

A Qt gui application shows data from a sql query in a QTableView. I append the data to the Table as QTableWidgetItems. After double clicking an item i want to get the id(primary key) of the item.

Since the id is not shown in the tableview I don't know how to get the id. The table should be able to be sorted which does not make it easier.

Is there a clean way to reference a row to an id without showing it in the table view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would use QTableWidgetItem::setData() function to store arbitrary types of data, associated with the table item.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Load data through QSqlQueryModel. Use a proxy model (QFilterSort...) to sort the columns. hide the xth column with QTableView to hide the primary key. Problem solved.